# How do I stop gradle from deleting my intermediate files before later tasks can consume them?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my Android Studio/gradle build I'm trying to automatically generate my app icon. The task that generates the icon image (a PNG) is being run at the correct time, but the image is being deleted before the task that consumes it runs.

This is a simplified version of what I've added to my `app/build.gradle` which illustrates the problem:

```groovy
task createIcon(type:Exec) {
    def outdir =
        new File("$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-ldpi/")
    outputs.dir(outdir)
    if (!outdir.exists()) {
        outdir.mkdirs()
    }
    def svg = 'src/images/ic_launcher.svg'
    inputs.source(new File(svg))
    def png = new File(outdir, "ic_launcher.png")
    outputs.file(png)
    commandLine "$workingDir/svgToPng.sh", svg, png
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded{ t ->
      if(t.name.equals("generateDebugAssets")){
          t.dependsOn createIcon
      }
}
```

If I run `./gradlew clean` and then `./gradlew assembleDebug`, I can see that the output file of my `createIcon` task, "app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png" is created and then very soon afterwards deleted. I get the following output from gradlew:

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
...
Bitmap saved as: /home/laurence/src/foo/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
/home/laurence/src/foo/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:13:23-44 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/laurence/.local/android-sdks/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

You can see that the task `:app:processDebugResources` fails because `aapt` claims it can't find `@drawable/ic_launcher` (the value of `android:icon` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`) which should correspond to the the place where I'm generating the PNG.

Note that I've confirmed that the PNG is being generated not just from the "Bitmap saved as" line in the console output, but also by watching the destination directory during the build. The file winks into existence and then vanishes a moment later.

Even weirder than that, if I run `./gradlew assembleDebug` a second time the build succeeds!

How do I prevent my generated PNG from being deleted and ensuring that `processDebugResources` can see it without having to run my build twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there were two smaller bugs, and one big bug.

One small bug was [pointed out by Lance Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248906/90848): the directory creation was being done in the configuration phase, rather than the execution phase. The other small bug was that this should have connected to `generateDebugResources`, not `generateDebugAssets`. Fixing these smaller bugs didn't solve the problem, however.

The big bug was that the files were being written to a sub-tree that was also being written to by another task. I was doing this because I didn't know how else to get the files picked up for inclusion in the assembly, but this was not the correct approach as the other task(s) that wrote to that sub-tree would sometimes stomp on the files (depending on what order the tasks executed), causing them to "vanish".

To fix all of these problems, the first step is to choose a new output directory for our task that won't interfere with other tasks:

```groovy
def fromSvgDir = file("$buildDir/generated/fromSvg/")
```

We then add this to the `srcDirs` for `res` in the existing `android` block near the top of the `build.gradle` file:

```groovy
sourceSets {
    main {
        res {
            srcDirs += fromSvgDir
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, have our task use that directory, and also fix those two other bugs:

```groovy
task createIcon(type:Exec) {
    def outdir = file("$fromSvgDir/drawable-ldpi/")
    outputs.dir(outdir)
    doFirst {
        outdir.mkdirs()
    }
    def svg = file('src/images/ic_launcher.svg')
    inputs.source(svg)
    def png = file("$outdir/ic_launcher.png")
    outputs.file(png)
    commandLine "$workingDir/svgToPng.sh", svg, png
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded{ t ->
      if(t.name.equals("generateDebugResources")){
          t.dependsOn createIcon
      }
}
```

This works reliably, and also has the advantage that the generated PNGs will go through the PNG cruncher just like the non-generated PNGs.

Comment: You should favour the [file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file(java.lang.Object)) convenience methods on the project object rather than explicitely instantiating a file object yourself. Eg `def fromSvgDir = file("$buildDir/generated/fromSvg/")` instead of `def fromSvgDir = new File(buildDir, "generated/fromSvg/")`

Comment: @LanceJava Thanks. I'm fairly new to gradle (and groovy) and so am not yet familiar with all the best practices. I've updated the answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you are creating the directory in the `configuration` phase rather than the `execution` phase (more info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/potential_traps.html#sec:configuration_and_execution_phase))

Try this instead:

```
task createIcon(type:Exec) {
    def svg = 'src/images/ic_launcher.svg'
    def outdir = file("$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-ldpi/")
    def png = new File(outdir, "ic_launcher.png")
    inputs.file(svg)
    outputs.dir(outdir)
    commandLine "$workingDir/pngToSvg.sh", png, svg
    doFirst {
        outdir.mkdirs()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That certainly looks like a bug, though it didn't actually solve my problem. After wrestling with it some more I finally came up with a solution, which I've posted as an answer.